# Search database for offensive words

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking on running a search on my database at set intervals for a list of words I consider offensive (because I am an authoritarian dictator and I hate free speech - I rule with an Iron fist).

How would I most efficiently search my database for a list of keywords? The two columns I intend to search are indexed as Fulltext.

If anyone knows of a list of offensive words that would be useful too.

**A note to those who ridicule my attempts at censorship**

I have will have two systems in place. The first is a report function which is checked daily by admins. The second tool to combat the dissenters is this one. All it needs to be is a word search so that the admin may check through and descide if the content is offensive or not.

Comment: Its probably worth noting that this is a genuine question - all jokes aside.

Comment: "How would I most efficiently search my database for a list of keywords?" Sorry - you have a list of words and would like to find instances in existing data, or use the search to create the list of words to be censored?

Comment: I mean I have a list of keywords and I search the database to find any instances of them... Sorry for my lack of clarity..

Comment: @Starlin: For an iron fisted dictator looking at censorship, you're rather apologetic =)

Comment: You are lucky my friend. Those who support my rein are treated with favour and are respected... those who oppose me however will feel my wrath. On a more serious note... this list looks good http://svn.navi.cx/misc/abandoned/opencombat/misc/multilingualSwearList.txt

Comment: @skilldrick - I am aware it is not fool proof. It is however better than nothing...

Comment: Love this answer for this kind of problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435727/check-message-for-bad-words-and-unseriousness-with-php/3435908#3435908

Comment: @Starkin - *buttholio*: Now that is an offensive word!

Comment: I think you have an extra "r" in your user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql won't give you the tools for an acurate search, take this sample, if you have among your words:

> **freedom**

Since you are a dictator you don't want it, it should appear, but clever users will put fr33dom, which is the same, now you have 3 ways to dot this:

1. You place in your list one word and
   most derivations you can imagine
2. You make a search with a LIKE in your MySql query, but it should be sloow when you hit the thousands, even with fulltext indexes
3. You Index your content using Lucene

I would go for the third, since Lucene is the best choice for performing searches, and since you are looking for words I can imagine that you are dealing with text, so this might help more than you think. Lucene can help you searching words similar to freedom, but not it, there you shouldn't miss much!! And your rule is guarrantied!

There are extensions for Lucene using Zend Framework, you can find them easily in Google.

Best of luck in your dictatorial efforst!

Comment: Lucene looks tough... I should have noted that I am looking for a quick solution... intended as a temporary solution for the launch of my application. I think I favour the first solution. The second will likely hit a lot of false positives too.

Comment: Also note you will be handsomely rewarded for you efforts. I never forget those who have supported me.

Comment: Thank you for your grace, my lord! hahaha. I hope I can help!

Answer (score 1):

here's your staring list!
http://onlineslangdictionary.com/lists/most-vulgar-words/
Check site for more

idea: DB their list, then screen against your DB. 
Or, DB their list, create all as key words, blocking entry. 
Then, use SQL wild card within words to check for:  freedom or Fr**dom,

But problems tech1 derivations are infinite.

Comment: If you can at least block Cl**eland St**mer you should be in the clear.

Comment: Most of those seem to be phrases rather than words, and rather contrived phrases at that.

Answer (score 1):

The link below leads to the list of 2200 bad words in 12 languages. MySQL dump, JSON, XML or CSV options are available.

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

Execute this dump into your own database and then query for any occurrence.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question and flag for undeletion.